# How do I set up a section of text on my home page to rotate through, rather than stay static?

Tags: entries, plugins, setup

I am a site owner who's new to Craft and whose site is nearing completion. I now realize I would like to have multiple versions of text rotate through in the box on the top of my home page, rather than having one "fixed" paragraph of text that doesn't change, unless I change it manually. (Think of scrolling testimonials, even though I don't plan to use it for that ...)

Will this change in setup require major surgery on the developer's part, minor surgery, or just a simple plugin, for example? Or might this functionality be built into Craft already? What's the upper limit on how many chunks of text I can have cycle through for the viewer to see?

Many thanks for your help and input!

Answer (score 3):

This should be relatively simple to implement, although depending on how the page was designed may require reworking some of the existing page layout and css.

As far as craft is concerned the data could be stored in a few different ways; perhaps in a separate channel, table, or matrix field. Setting this up on the craft-side is trivial, and would not require any special plugins.

On the front-end content could all be loaded when the template is initially rendered (by simply adding a few lines of code to the template), or loaded as needed using javascript and ajax (by creating a separate template used to render just the text segments as requested). Although if it's truly only text, I would opt for loading it all at once on initial page load. Transitions would normally be done using some fairly simple javascript and/or css transitions.

There shouldn't be any technical limit on the number of items you could display; but there probably are some practical limits where it would start to get clumsy for one reason or another.

If you need more specific code examples, please leave a comment, and I can add more detail.